# Bootstrap Theme - variables.less - Bootswatch

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

How do you generate bootstrap.css file from the variables.less and bootstrap.less files from http://bootswatch.com/ ?

Compiling using lessC, I get a css file but that is way smaller than bootstrap.css. How am I supposed to change the colour in one of the themes?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Bootswatch Swatchmaker

Thomas Park, the maker and maintainer of Bootswatch, made a little kit called **Swatchmaker** specifically for the purposes of customizing themes from Bootswatch or creating new ones.

Check out [the Swatchmaker readme in his Bootswatch repo on GitHub](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/tree/master/swatchmaker) for more info.

Once you get that set up, just add the LESS files for the theme you want to edit to the `swatch` directory, editing the **variables.less** with your customizations.

The contents of the **swatchmaker.less** gives a decent summary of what it does:

```
@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "swatch/variables.less";
@import "swatch/bootswatch.less";
@import "bootstrap/less/utilities.less";
```

Then **bootstrap.css** is generated from `lessc swatchmaker.less > bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I still get the error                                                               root@ubuntu:/var/www/clipr/output/css/theme1/bootstrap-2.2.1/less# lessc bootstrap.less
NameError: #grid > .core is undefined in grid.less:7:0
6 // Fixed (940px)
7 #grid > .core(@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth);
8

Comment: Which theme are you trying to use? I just tested a few using Bootswatch's Swatchmaker and they built fine. That error sounds like an issue with your **mixins.less** which Bootswatch doesn't touch AFAIK.

Comment: swatchmaker worked for me. Thanks a ton. Though the manual process (method 1) did not work.

Comment: Yeah, I just dropped the manual version and instead added more details on Swatchmaker so a manual method can be inferred.  It turned out to be a little different than what I initially anticipated.

Comment: github gives 404 it's dead

Answer (score 23):

Bootswatch Swatchmaker is great and all but sometimes you are trying include Bootswatch themes in a more scriptable environment or need a better understanding of how Bootswatch themes are put together. Here is my method for **manually** compiling a Bootswatch Theme.

1. Download Twitter Bootstrap from the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and uncompress.
2. Move the Bootswatch files `variables.less` and `bootswatch.less` to the `less/` folder, replacing the existing `variables.less` file.
3. At the end of `bootstrap.less`, append `@import "bootswatch.less";`.
4. Compile `bootstrap.less`. I recommend using the [grunt task provided by Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt).

Comment: Good solution if you don't care much for the makefiles. Using this with express less middleware.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use webcompiler in vs2017 to compile bootswatch into my project using this technique. When I use bower to bring in bootstrap the less files are already present, I usually start with a bootswatch template and modifiy, but older technique wasn't working. Following your instructions worked perfectly with webcompiler in vs2017. I was able to start manually compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this as a "supplemental" answer (@merv has already given the correct answer!), but just in case it's useful to anyone:

My problem was that I want to use just the bootstrap.less and variables.less file to generate a new theme in a way that simply used the Grunt tasks already developed in the Bootstrap distribution. I didn't want to install any Bootswatch-specific tools to compile a new theme.

I already have a modified build script that uses the core bootstrap from path /lib/bootstrap. I consider the theme to be a part of the lib as well, but I gave it its own directory: /lib/theme

Inside the theme directory, I put the two files downloaded from http://bootswatch.com -- namely, "bootswatch.less" and "variables.less". Thing is, these two files don't really "do anything" by themselves; they still rely on Bootstrap. So hooking it all up meant CREATING a third file, which I called "theme.less". The contents of theme.less are as described by @merv above:

```
@import "../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "bootswatch.less";
@import "../bootstrap/less/utilities.less";
```

Your paths will be different depending on how you've structured your project. Then, in the Gruntfile.js (modified from the one included in Bootstrap), you locate the compileTheme configuration object and modify it to point to this new theme.less file:

```
compileTheme: {
    options: {
      strictMath: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      outputSourceFiles: true,
      sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
      sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
    },
    src: 'lib/theme/theme.less',
    dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
  }
```

It's only the "src" line that has changed.

Now when you run > `grunt dist` (or any other related grunt tasks) it will pick up the theme from the new location, apply the appropriate parts of Bootstrap's included files, and produce a new theme.

Hope that's helpful to anyone. It doesn't answer the OP directly since it's a bootstrap-theme.css file rather than a bootstrap.css file, but it's more in line with what people tend to do with Bootstrap 3.2+ as of this writing. And more importantly, for those who are relative newcomers to all things LESS and Grunt, it's a fairly pain-free way to modify the build script without overwriting files in the bootstrap directory.